# Difference between Featured Video and Related Video?

Tags: video

I'm creating a video site like Youtube. The problem is that I can't understand the difference between Related and Featured videos. If i have a video in News category what will be his related and featured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Featured Videos will be primarily populated with videos from YouTube's
>   thousands of partners, but might also include select user videos that
>   are currently popular or that we have previously showcased in
>   Spotlight Videos. We will automatically rotate these videos throughout
>   the day to keep them fresh. Featured Videos are not advertisements or
>   paid placements, but do feature content from partners with whom we
>   have a commercial relationship.

Source: http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=143421

EDITED:

Well, and the related video are videos with common content, keywords, etc. To classify really well what is a related video, you should collect information of the tittle, description, comments and all meta information available and give them certain weights to make a "score" and place the highest scores occupying the best positions.

The Featured videos as you can see above, Youtube just place whatever they want to place. Could be some paid video or ad (or euphemistically a video of a partner that you have commercial relationship), a very popular video about the subject that the user is searching, etc.